# How to install PoCL(Portable Computing Language) on a Windows system?

Tags: windows, installation, opencl, amd-gpu, pocl

Like the title implied, I'm currently trying to install/use PoCL in a Visual Studio project, but I'm completely lost as to how to do that. I wasn't able to find any guides or tutorials on the topic and the documentation on their website apparently only covered Linux and not Windows. I would be very grateful if anyone has a guide/tutorial or directions on how to solve this issue!

Since it might be helpful: I'm using Windows 10, and a Ryzen 5 4500U. GPU-Z confirms that the Vega 6 (the GPU portion of the APU) supports OpenCL.

Additionally:
I tried to follow the directions of the `README.windows`, which was part of the Zip I downloaded from GitHub and sadly the only form of helpful documentation I was able to find up to this point. The following command was what I tried in the Git Bash:

```
MINGW64 ~
$ curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pocl/master/windows/setup_and_build_win64.sh | sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    14  100    14    0     0     60      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--    61
sh: line 1: 404:: command not found
```

I was not able to figure out why the sh command could not be found yet, nor if I am on the right path with this attempt. What I should add, is that I didn't install Visual Studio 2013 yet, since I wanted to try if Visual Studio 2019 works first. I apologize if it might be the root of the problem!

Comment: update : Fixed here https://github.com/pocl/pocl/commit/a0b84a294d0e09c58541aa67b930239700884827

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RawGit service is no longer available, and I've raised an [issuse](https://github.com/pocl/pocl/issues/984#issue-983800538). You can directly run the setup_and_build_win64.sh in Git bash from the zip you've downloaded [/pocl/windows/setup_and_build_win64.sh]